# Unable to get hyperlink label for .docx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, docx

My goal is to count the number of times a docs.google.com type of hyperlink appears in a MS Word Document (.docx).

In addition to counting a hyperlink, I am also trying to count "plain text" which contains "docs.google.com" in it.

For e.g., consider a word document which has the following text:

```
https://docs.google.com/1234
```

https://docs.google.com/1235
[Link to doc](https://docs.google.com/1236)

According to my desired logic, the total number of links should be 1 + 2 + 1 = 4.
The second one is 2 because the display value is a google doc link as well as the target URL is a google doc link.

I am having trouble in getting the display values for the "plain text" type of links in my Java code below:

```
int[] getNumGDocLinksFromWord(String filepath) {

    int [] numLinks = {0, 0};
    File file = new File(filepath);

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
      XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
      List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
      for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
        numLinks[0] += numOccurrences(para.getText(), GOOG_DOC_URL_HOST);
        for(XWPFRun run : para.getRuns()) {
          if(run instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
            XWPFHyperlink link = ((XWPFHyperlinkRun)run).getHyperlink(document);
            if(link != null && link.getURL().contains(GOOG_DOC_URL_HOST)) {
              numLinks[1]++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numLinks;
}


private int numOccurrences(String text, String sequence) {
    int n = 0, i = 0;
    while (i != -1) {
      i = text.indexOf(sequence, i + 1);
      if (i != -1) {
        n++;
      }
    }
    return n;
}
```

numLinks[0] captures the display value occurrences and numLinks[1](https://docs.google.com/1236) captures the hyperlink's target value occurrences.

Can someone please tell me how can I accurately count these two types of values?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Having `static String GOOG_DOC_URL_HOST = "docs.google.com";` and your described word document, your code produces `numLinks[0]` and `numLinks[1]` both being `2` for me, which is correct. No?

Comment: @AxelRichter, try the same thing with this document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cru63h5wm4ll3zu/test2.docx?dl=0. numLinks should be [3,3] but it is coming out to be [2,3]. I added some print statements, and it doesn't seem to be picking up the display value of "http://docs.google.com/doc3".

Comment: In `/word/document.xml` there is: `<w:p ...>...<w:hyperlink ...><w:hyperlink ...><w:r ...>...<w:t>http://docs.google.com/doc</w:t></w:r></w:hyperlink><w:r ...>...<w:t>3</w:t></w:r></w:hyperlink></w:p>`. As you see the text `http://docs.google.com/doc` is a text run within a hyperlink within a outer hyperlink. The text `3` is a text run within the outer hyperlink. This is nothing what `apache poi` takes into account until now. But according the XML definition in Ecma-376 it **is** possible that `CT_Hyperlink` can contain other `CT_Hyperlink`. So it is a bug in `apache poi`.